# I have a bunch of incomplete degrees. Any chance to get in decent Masters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, undergraduate, united-kingdom

I have a bunch of incomplete degrees. I nearly finished one bachelor's but the 16h work days made me focus on work instead of academia. Then I tried with other degrees but never got far in any of them.

Now I found a bachelor's and master's that I want to pursue. Would I still have a chance to get in a master's degree in the UK, USA or Canada if I keep a decent GPA during bachelor's? I imagine Ivies are out of question. I also have 5+ years of work experience and a disability (hard of hearing) which has been steering my life choices for a long time, I.e. I thought it's better to devote myself to work in order to gain skills and make myself attractive in work market just in case something goes wrong with my current work.

Comment: In what area are you planning to do your Master's? Will that area overlap with the area of your work? Simply speaking, is there a chance that your work experience adds weight to your application? Another question: if, suppose, you devote yourself to work, will that make you a happy person? Or will that fill your future life with regrets?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I intend to apply for a degree in line with my work. I think I'll be happy to be able to think strategically and have some intellectual discussion. I'm also gunning for a chance to participate in a research though I need yet to invent the topic.

Comment: Is there a negative to just trying and applying? I understand that you want to do the bachelor anyway?

Comment: @Karolina If your desired Master's is to be in line with your work, then you should get maximum out of your CV. When applying, explain that this is a mature decision based on your experience in the area. Potential advisors like applicants who are mature and know exactly what they want and why they apply. Also, you may consider mentioning in your CV only the degree you intend to complete. You may, though, mention that you "took courses" on various subjects. I wish you good luck with your Bachelors -- and then, hopefully, Masters!

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I don't see any negatives in just trying but I was wondering how to frame my application so I do get accepted. Some of more prestigious universities have programmes that fit in with my work experience so I think I'm going to be trying out that route.

Comment: Are you planning to do a bachelor degree first? If so I don't see any reason why you would struggle any more in the application than anyone else who did that bachelor degree (and got the same marks as you)

Answer (score 1):

### Start with finishing your bachelor degree.

You haven't finished your bachelor's degree, and you want to get a masters? I'd say the first step is to finish your bachelor's. Apply for it, and then talk to them about recognition of prior knowledge for the partially-completed degrees you attempted.

Depending on how relevant the courses you took in your previous degree are to the degree you're applying for, you may be able to start off basically where you left off with your previous degree.

Answer (score 0):

Work experience is sometimes considered more important than other scores as it shows your have worked in real world environment. I believe you should highlight your work experience in your experience and you will definitely be a stronger candidate as compared to those who don’t have work ex. In addition, if you took the courses from accredited schools and is related with your field of work you might be able to transfer those towards your MS. Good luck! With your bachelors and future masters

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on field,  but if you do get a bachelor, get a good grade in that,  then I don't see you having a problem getting admittance to a UK masters degree.